# Magento 2 minicart only homepage empty

Tags: cart, mini-cart, magento-2.1.3

From few days I will trying to figure out strange issue. My cart shows empty ONLY on home page, for each other page shows count good.

What is wrong?

Comment: is cache is enabled for your website ?

Comment: better to clear cache from CLI and enable it. Clean and flush both. did you do any customization...and add code of your mini.cart file here to check.

Comment: @Lucas, Have you solved this issue?

Answer (score 0):

I using Varnish, I always delete all cache files and deploying new, before I check, so this is not cache.

I am only add social icon to this template. As I mentioned everywhere cart show quantity, only on home page is qmpty

```
    <?php
/**
 * Copyright © 2016 Magento. All rights reserved.
 * See COPYING.txt for license details.
 */

// @codingStandardsIgnoreFile

/** @var $block \Magento\Checkout\Block\Cart\Sidebar */
?>
<div class="social">
<!--    <a href=""><img src="<?php echo $this->getViewFileUrl('images/fb.svg'); ?>" /> -->
    <a target="_blank" href="https://www.instagram.com/caltikbros/">
<!-- Generator: Adobe Illustrator 19.0.0, SVG Export Plug-In . SVG Version: 6.00 Build 0)  -->
<svg version="1.1" id="Layer_1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" x="0px" y="0px"
     viewBox="5 -5 40 40" style="width: 30px; height: 30px;" xml:space="preserve">
<style type="text/css">
    .st0{fill-opacity:0;stroke:#000000;stroke-width:3;stroke-linejoin:round;}
    .st1{clip-path:url(#SVGID_2_);fill:#13110C;}
    .st2{fill:#13110C;}
</style>
<circle class="st0" cx="25" cy="15" r="18.5"/>
<g>
    <g>
        <defs>
            <polygon id="SVGID_1_" points="13.8,26.2 36.2,26.2 36.2,3.8 13.8,3.8 13.8,26.2          "/>
        </defs>
        <clipPath id="SVGID_2_">
            <use xlink:href="#SVGID_1_"  style="overflow:visible;"/>
        </clipPath>
        <path class="st1" d="M25,3.8c-3,0-3.4,0-4.6,0.1c-1.2,0.1-2,0.2-2.7,0.5c-0.7,0.3-1.4,0.7-2,1.3c-0.6,0.6-1,1.2-1.3,2
            c-0.3,0.7-0.5,1.5-0.5,2.7c-0.1,1.2-0.1,1.6-0.1,4.6c0,3,0,3.4,0.1,4.6c0.1,1.2,0.2,2,0.5,2.7c0.3,0.7,0.7,1.4,1.3,2
            c0.6,0.6,1.2,1,2,1.3c0.7,0.3,1.5,0.5,2.7,0.5c1.2,0.1,1.6,0.1,4.6,0.1s3.4,0,4.6-0.1c1.2-0.1,2-0.2,2.7-0.5
            c0.7-0.3,1.4-0.7,2-1.3c0.6-0.6,1-1.2,1.3-2c0.3-0.7,0.5-1.5,0.5-2.7c0.1-1.2,0.1-1.6,0.1-4.6c0-3,0-3.4-0.1-4.6
            c-0.1-1.2-0.2-2-0.5-2.7c-0.3-0.7-0.7-1.4-1.3-2c-0.6-0.6-1.2-1-2-1.3c-0.7-0.3-1.5-0.5-2.7-0.5C28.4,3.8,28,3.8,25,3.8 M25,5.8
            c3,0,3.3,0,4.5,0.1c1.1,0,1.7,0.2,2.1,0.4c0.5,0.2,0.9,0.4,1.3,0.8c0.4,0.4,0.6,0.8,0.8,1.3c0.2,0.4,0.3,1,0.4,2.1
            c0.1,1.2,0.1,1.5,0.1,4.5c0,3,0,3.3-0.1,4.5c0,1.1-0.2,1.7-0.4,2.1c-0.2,0.5-0.4,0.9-0.8,1.3c-0.4,0.4-0.8,0.6-1.3,0.8
            c-0.4,0.2-1,0.3-2.1,0.4c-1.2,0.1-1.5,0.1-4.5,0.1s-3.3,0-4.5-0.1c-1.1,0-1.7-0.2-2.1-0.4c-0.5-0.2-0.9-0.4-1.3-0.8
            c-0.4-0.4-0.6-0.8-0.8-1.3c-0.2-0.4-0.3-1-0.4-2.1c-0.1-1.2-0.1-1.5-0.1-4.5c0-3,0-3.3,0.1-4.5c0-1.1,0.2-1.7,0.4-2.1
            c0.2-0.5,0.4-0.9,0.8-1.3c0.4-0.4,0.8-0.6,1.3-0.8c0.4-0.2,1-0.3,2.1-0.4C21.7,5.8,22,5.8,25,5.8"/>
    </g>
    <path class="st2" d="M25,18.7c-2.1,0-3.7-1.7-3.7-3.7c0-2.1,1.7-3.7,3.7-3.7c2.1,0,3.7,1.7,3.7,3.7C28.7,17.1,27.1,18.7,25,18.7
         M25,9.3c-3.2,0-5.7,2.6-5.7,5.7c0,3.2,2.6,5.7,5.7,5.7s5.7-2.6,5.7-5.7C30.7,11.8,28.2,9.3,25,9.3"/>
    <path class="st2" d="M32.3,9c0,0.7-0.6,1.3-1.3,1.3c-0.7,0-1.3-0.6-1.3-1.3c0-0.7,0.6-1.3,1.3-1.3C31.7,7.7,32.3,8.3,32.3,9"/>
</g>
</svg>

    </a>
<!--    <a href=""><img src="<?php echo $this->getViewFileUrl('images/pin.svg'); ?>" /> -->
</div>

<div data-block="minicart" class="minicart-wrapper">
    <a class="level-top-a" href="/our-story/"><span>About</span></a>
    <a onclick='window.location.href = "http://eu.caltikbros.com/checkout/cart/"' class="action showcart" href="<?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo $block->getShoppingCartUrl(); ?>"
       data-bind="scope: 'minicart_content'">
        <span class="caltik-text"><?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo __('My Cart'); ?></span>
        (<span class="counter qty empty"
              data-bind="css: { empty: !!getCartParam('summary_count') == false }, blockLoader: isLoading">
            <span class="counter-number"><!-- ko text: getCartParam('summary_count') --><!-- /ko --></span>
            <span class="counter-label">
            <!-- ko if: getCartParam('summary_count') -->
                <!-- ko text: getCartParam('summary_count') --><!-- /ko -->
                <!-- ko i18n: 'items' --><!-- /ko -->
            <!-- /ko -->
            </span>
        </span>)
    </a>
    <?php if ($block->getIsNeedToDisplaySideBar()): ?>
        <div class="block block-minicart empty"
             data-role="dropdownDialog"
             data-mage-init='{"dropdownDialog":{
                "appendTo":"[data-block=minicart]",
                "triggerTarget":".showcart",
                "timeout": "2000",
                "closeOnMouseLeave": false,
                "closeOnEscape": true,
                "triggerClass":"active",
                "parentClass":"active",
                "buttons":[]}}'>
            <div id="minicart-content-wrapper" data-bind="scope: 'minicart_content'">
                <!-- ko template: getTemplate() --><!-- /ko -->
            </div>
            <?php echo $block->getChildHtml('minicart.addons'); ?>
        </div>
    <?php endif ?>
    <script>
        window.checkout = <?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo \Zend_Json::encode($block->getConfig()); ?>;
    </script>
    <script type="text/x-magento-init">
    {
        "[data-block='minicart']": {
            "Magento_Ui/js/core/app": <?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo $block->getJsLayout();?>
        },
        "*": {
            "Magento_Ui/js/block-loader": "<?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo $block->getViewFileUrl('images/loader-1.gif'); ?>"
        }
    }
    </script>
</div>
```